# Deleting character in strings VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to think of a way to format the SSN numbers of our clients in a excel spreadsheet to take out all "-".

example:   123-45-6789 turns into 123456789

All my other sources have failed and I didn't find anything on here that helped me.

edit: I will need this to work on an entire column

Comment: `Replace(ssn,"-","")`

Comment: will this do it for the entire column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the cells you wish to process and run this short macro:

```
Sub Ken()
    Dim r As Range, v As String

    For Each r In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        v = r.Text
        If v <> "" Then
            r.NumberFormat = "@"
            r.Value = Replace(v, "-", "")
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: how would i apply this to all of column "C"?

Comment: Just `Select` column **C** and run the macro.................the macro should run quickly since it does **not** process the vast sea of empty cells at the bottom of most columns.

Comment: gotcha, Thanks a lot